# How to cache a dtd file when parsing xml in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dtd

I am parsing a few million xml files with that are formatted like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE test-document PUBLIC "-//TEST//TEST DOC//EN" "https://somerandomurl.com/test.dtd">
<test-document>...</test-document>
```

Every time I am parsing a file the same `https://somerandomurl.com/test.dtd` file is downloaded and that consumes a lot of bandwidth and seems unnecessary. Is there a way to store the file and have my code redirect my local copy? I can't edit the xml files so it has to be in my code. Given the following java code what would be a reasonable way to implement such a thing?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
factory.setValidating(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource("file.xml"));//My final document object.
```

Comment: why are you parsing that many files...

Comment: @Lino got a data set from an organization that has a few million records and each one is in its own xml file. Need to parse each one of them to be able to get the data into the desired format which isn't millions of xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to cache downloaded DTD files, way to go is using XML catalogs. In particular, you'd be specifying, in a resolution rule in a catalog file such as the following

```
<catalog
  Xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
  <system
    systemId="https://somerandomurl.com/test.dtd"
    uri="file://mydir/test.dtd"/>
</catalog>
```

that the entity with system identifier `https://somerandomurl.com/test.dtd` is resolved as the file `/mydir/test.dtd` which should contain a downloaded local copy of the DTD file linked to by the https: URL.

#### Links

- https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/03/03/catalogs.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/core/xml-catalog-api1.htm#JSCOR-GUID-96D2C9AC-641A-4BDB-BB08-9FA04358A6F4
- https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/spec-2001-08-06.html#s.system

Comment: Using a catalog seems a bit heavyweight for this. The DTD is still being read from disk each time, even though it's no longer being fetched from the internet. Also, unless you're careful, the catalog itself will be parsed each time. My solution uses an EntityResolver to read the DTD from an in-memory string.

Answer (score 2):

First read the DTD into a string variable.

Then do

```
builder.setEntityResolver(
     (sysId, PubId) -> new InputSource(new StringReader(dtd)));
```

Or if you want to be more careful, have your EntityResolver check that the systemId and/or publicId are as expected before returning the contents of `dtd`.

Note that this will still involve parsing the DTD each time, it just saves the cost of fetching it from the network.

**Also important:** instantiating the XML parser is a significant cost (and instantiating a DocumentBuilderFactory is even bigger). Make sure you reuse both the factory and the parser.